# How to implement Ext js Calender in version 4.2

Tags: extjs

> I am getting error when trying to implement Ext js Pro calendar in ext js 4.2
>   error is Cannot read property '**add' of undefined** in line `var startDate = Extensible.Date.add(Ext.Date.clearTime(start || new Date(), true))` in AbstarctCalndar.js;
>   My intail Code is

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
enabled: true,
disableCaching: false,
paths: {
   "Extensible": "extjs/src/extensible/src",
   "Extensible.example": "extjs/src/extensible/examples"
}
});
Ext.require([
'Extensible.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore',
'Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel',
'Extensible.example.calendar.data.Events'
]);
```

> Here is simple code in app.js

```
Ext.onReady(function () {

var eventStore = Ext.create('Extensible.calendar.data.MemoryEventStore', {

    // defined in ../data/Events.js
data:  [{
        "id": 1001,
        "CalendarId": 1,
        "StartDate": "2015-03-18",
        "EndDate": "2015-03-28",
        "Title": "Vacation",
        "Notes": "Have fun"
    }]
});

//
// example 1: simplest possible stand-alone configuration
//
    var cal = new Ext.create('Extensible.calendar.CalendarPanel', {
    eventStore: eventStore,

    title: 'Basic Calendar',
    width: 700,
    height: 500
});
     Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 100,
        height : 100,
        border : true,
        frame : true,
        layout: 'auto',// auto is one of the layout type.
        items: [cal]
     });
  });
```

> Please give sample data of Event store data and Calendar Store Data.
>   Please suggest working code both in MVC and onReady

Comment: Can you please give some more info about your AbstarctCalndar.js

Comment: its a library file inbuilt .Even am new to it. Probably it is called to set date for calendar

Comment: ok. possibly it is missing something for `Extensible.Date` and therefor error is appearing. will get back to u once found something.